# change the Colour/markerFill in an Apex Line Series?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I have a line series :

```
<apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="Date" yField="Opportunity Name" markerType="circle" markerSize="4" markerFill="#8E35EF" />
```

Is it possible to change the markerType/markerFill based on a value of a field in the same object Opportunity?
e.g if x field = good , colour should be green .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way - is to display lineSeries with no markers and display two scatterSeries, where some data is not rendered on a chart.

VF:

```
<apex:chart height="400" width="700" data="{!data}">
<apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data1" title="Lines" grid="true"/>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Month"/>

    <apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="data1" markerType="circle"
                     markerSize="0" markerFill="#515151" strokeColor="515151"/>
    <apex:scatterSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="data2" 
                        markerType="circle" markerSize="4" markerFill="#1919ff"/>
    <apex:scatterSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="data3" 
                        markerType="circle" markerSize="4" markerFill="#B0171F"/>
</apex:chart>
```

Apex:

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<Data> getRemoteData() {
    return ChartController.getChartData();
}

public static List<Data> getChartData() {
    List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
    data.add(new Data('Jan', 30, -10, 30));
    data.add(new Data('Feb', 44, 44, -10));
    data.add(new Data('Mar', 25, 25, -10));
    data.add(new Data('Apr', 74, -10, 74));
    return data;
}
```

You can populate your data in controller based on some condition. Chart will not display dots where Y-axis is -10.

[image: Chart with colorful markers]

*I believe, there should be better solution with rendererFn, but its not ordinary*

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I have divided my data into 3 lists . Can you help me with the syntax as to how to I put them ?

Comment: I have divided my data by using 3 parts. I have created 3 fields and only 1 set of data will have a value in the field . Else it will have null. How do I use it here?